# Switching to an aliased directory

Tags: macos, shell, directory, alias

Just wanted to know if it is possible to switch to an aliased directory using shell script.

To switch to a directory there is cd command. But i have aliased the directory and wanted to know as how to switch to the aliased directory.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias is meant to be a shortcut for a **command**.

You can't `cd` to an aliased directory.

But if you have a variable referencing that directory, you can. e.g.

```
dev="/path/to/my/dev"    
cd $dev
```

Or set up an alias to cd to the directory:

```
alias dev='cd /path/to/my/dev'
```

Comment: I am using Mac OS and i have created an alias of a directory by right clicking on the directory and choosing Make Alias menu. Now, i want to cd the aliased directory which i am unable to do.

Comment: I tried assigning the path of the aliased directory to a variable and then cd it. But its still not working.